# PHP and MySQL high traffic solution

Tags: php, mysql, database, scalability

Consider the creation of high traffic PHP web-site with many parallel users. Which is the best possible MySQL abstraction (ORM or OODBMS) in terms of effectiveness (15-20 database tables with sum of about 100000 items and JOIN queries between no more than 4 tables)?

Somewhere I heard that Doctrine libraries are appropriate or I should use framework like Zend? Which of these database solutions are build over PDO and don't require much learning (at this time I'm using pure PHP)?

Comment: You should use the solution *most suited to the problem*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ORM or any data modeling layer will never get you better performance. Their sole purposes is to make your development time faster and easier to maintain. They are notoriously bad at decision making when it comes to actually using relationships appropriately and end up querying all tables in order to find the correct data. At that level of complex queries you are not going to be able to abstract away these relationships without sacrificing performance.

MySQL is fine for up to a couple million records at least (I've used it for over 100 million in a single table). For performance sake you generally want to have at least a master/slave setup and some method of distributing reads between them. The database will almost always be the limiting factor in performance. You can always add in more web servers and get a load balance in front of them to solve the other side of things but the database setup is always a little harder to maintain.

You have to think about why you want to use an ORM. If its for development reasons, that's fine, but be coginiscent that your performance will suffer. Otherwise stick to queries. An ORM adds a third layer of code to deal with and learn. If you know PHP and MySQL, do you need to learn a 3rd language to use them effectively? Most often the answer is no.

You have many options to choose from but be aware that at some point the framework/ORM you choose will not behave the way you want it to and to get it to behave to your desires you will have to do a lot of searching and digging through code. It's the classic problem - save time up front and pay for it later or spend time up front with no possible payoff later.

Comment: Thanks. And what is your opinion of this OODBMS solution Doctrine because I read that it's built over PDO. Is Doctrine better solution than pure queries?

Comment: In terms of what? Performance? No. Usability? Depends on your opinion. I personally feel more at home crafting queries than object abstractions but I've recently been using CakePHP at work and understand that it does make things easier when you don't have to worry about it. I've used Doctrine with Symfony and it's okay but you end up writing pseudo-SQL anyway through their functions so at that level I end up asking myself "What's the point?". I already know SQL so abstracting that out while limiting the queries I can write it just doesn't end up being helpful.

Comment: For example: `$items = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('Example e')->leftJoin('e.Foobar')->where('e.id = ?', 20)->execute();` vs raw SQL. If you know SQL then this is just another layer of complexity. If not, then it might make sense to use an ORM until you learn the ins and outs of SQL queries.

Comment: What about the query and results caching features of most ORMs? I feel these usually make up for any overhead, the alternative being to roll your own

Comment: MySQL has built in query caching so again, raw queries will ALWAYS perform better than an ORM if you know how to write queries. If not it's probably a wash. Think of the amount of code, also, that has to be run to maintain these relationships from a query resultset. It's very substantial and something you have very little control over. For a novice, though, it would be perfectly adequate but I would hope a novice would not be in a position to build a high-performance piece of software.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless of the DB solution you should look at using a system like [MemCached](http://memcached.org/). With the proper caching strategy you will significantly reduce the load your databases are putting on your server.

There is a PHP API for memcached [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php)

Comment: [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php) is another shared memory cache solution

Comment: Update: APC is being phased out in later releases of PHP (starting from 5.5). It is being replaced by Zend OPCache, which does not support user caching. So if you think you're going to head into later versions of PHP without needing a code rewrite, you should consider not using APC at all.

Answer (score 1):

ORM solutions will be able to optimize some aspects, if you cache query data and use the object API in a planned and deliberate way.

Column / document[nosql : hbase,mongo] databases will improve performance if you have lots (millions+) of records, and are still growing.

Memcached will help if you have a lot of spare memory and especially if there are a lot of repetitious queries being run.